# _OBJC_CLASS_$ errors on M1 Macbook - Google Maps-Places

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

I recently moved my code base from an old intel based macbook to a new M1 based macbook.  All of my cocoapods went to hell, so I swapped all of them for swift packages and completely removed all traces of cocoapods from my code base.

Everything appears to be working fine except for this OBJC_CLASS_$ error when I compile that appears to be google maps/places related (I have packages for both & use both in my app).

I've tried everything per other threads(switching up architecture settings) but nothing has worked to get rid of these errors.  I can't even find GMS named files in my code anywhere.  Thoughts??  thanks!

[image: error messages]

Comment: Are you using the same version of macOS/Xcode as previously?

Comment: @shim yes - same macOS version (Ventura) and same xcode (14.2).  I played around with xcode 15 once and had so many errors I didn't try again.  Not sure if I need a newer version though, 14.2 has been the most stable for me.

Comment: This happens when you try to compile a simulator build for an arm64-based Mac with a library that doesn't have an arm64 simulator slice in its binary. Are you on an old version of the Google Maps SDK? They only just added support for arm64 simulators in version 7.3 in January of this year

Comment: THANK YOU! @MichaelHulet. That was the problem,I've updated to 7.3 (I was on 7.1) and the error has gone away.